# Shift/reduce issue in bison due to empty rule

Tags: bison, context-free-grammar

I have the following grammar in bison that generates shift/reduce conflicts:

```
%token  a

%start A
%% 

A: a B C | /* empty */
;
B: D E
;
E: D E | /* empty */
;
D: error
;
C: error
;
```

How can I rewrite the grammar without using precedence?

Comment: Having rules that *only* expand to error, with no non-error productions doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  That means that any the requires them (anything except &epsilon; here) will trigger a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem here is that you have an ambiguity in error recovery between C and D.  After recovering the first error<sup>1</sup> (as a D), any subsequent error can be recovered as either a C or a D, which is ambiguous.  So you need to rethink what it is you are actually trying to do -- there are no (non-empty) inputs that can be recognized without an error, so it doesn't make much sense.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Actually, you can't even recover from the first error, as there's nothing that can legally follow a D, so it will immediately re-error (and throw away more tokens) -- the net result being that it will simply discard the rest of the input and then return a parse failure.  You might be able to get something further with an action that explicitly set `yyerrok`, but its not clear what the point would be</sub>

Comment: If error will be replaced by a new token f it's still have conflicts

Comment: If you change to a 'real' token, then you have a simple shift-reduce conflict due to needing two tokens of lookahead to find the end of a `B`.  You can fix that by getting rid of the redundant C non-terminal (as it is the same as D) and then refactoring B to have the extra `D`/`f` at the beginning instead of the end.  Then your grammar is just `A: a f B | /*empty*/ ; B: f | B f ;`